# I'm having a hard time changing the result of a url in iis rewrite. can you help me?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

**Original URL:** http://localhost:83/glad.mcExperienceSuite/
**I want this url to look like this:** http://localhost:83/glad

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <remove name="teste" />
            <rule name="Rewrite_Glad">
                <match url="^(.*)glad" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(.*)glad" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: Enable FRT to see what's happening under the hood, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules and then you can help yourself.

Comment: Hello. URL Rewrite is a server side mechanism to rewrite the URL before it is processed by IIS. It has nothing to do with "how it looks" on the client. That being said, if you want a request that comes from a client and matches the regex defined in `match` to look like that, simply add `<action type="Rewrite" url="http://{SERVER_NAME}/glad" />`. You don't need any captured groups here, if this is indeed what you want.

Answer (score 0):

SERVER_NAME is the hostname, DNS alias, or IP address of the server, not including the port number.

Only for the URL in the example you provided, you can try the following rules to see if it is feasible, and then expand and supplement the rules.

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rewrite_Glad">
                <match url="^glad"/>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}/glad.mcExperienceSuite" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) for an example of creating rewrite rules for the URL Rewrite module.
If there is a rewrite error, using `Failed Request Tracing` to trace rewrite rules.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but when I try to type http://localhost:83/glad it reports an HTTP 404 -Not Found error, the physical path it is reading is in the "Not Found" error is C:\inetpub\ wwwroot\Chronos\glad and it should be the original
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Chronos\glad.mcexperiencesuite.
  I would just like to be able to call the url http://localhost:83/glad and it already understands that I am calling the http://localhost:83/glad.mcexperiencesuite.

Comment: I wonder if `glad.mcexperiencesuite` is a folder in your website path?